# Click_no_wait is throwing this following error when I try to click a button

Tags: ruby, watir

When I use click_no_wait function as shown below,

```
begin
  $browser.buttons[1].click_no_wait
rescue =>e
  puts e.message
end
```

It throws this following error

```
"undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass"
```

Can anyone please guide me why this error happens and How could I
resolve this problem?

Comment: Remove the begin-rescue-end to output the whole error, then add it to your question.

Comment: please write the value of `button` variable.

Comment: Most likely your `buttons` does not contain two elements. If you want the first element, keep in mind theat indexes are 0 based.

Comment: @Rogue_Leader, What is the difference, both are one,isn't it?

Comment: @SachinSingh It's not exactly button, so value is not here, but I accomplish through '$browser.button(:class,'GoButton').click_no_wait', it's working fine now ,thanks.

Comment: @BroiSatse Thanks for you comment, but I am aware of the fact that it's starts from index 0, and problem was not that, because I couldn't click that element using the above code, but I couldn't use click_no_wait methods on that. however I achieved through '$browser.button(:class,'GoButton').click_no_wait'

Comment: No, the code you've given will only return the error name, not the stack trace, which is vital iun order to pin down exactly where the error is thrown.

In any case, this is not a stable way to locate elements. You should use an ID -- 

$browser.button(id: 'my_login_button').click_no_wait --

or at least a class name --

    $browser.buttons(class: 'default-submit-button')[1].click_no_wait --

if possible

Comment: @Rogue_Leader Ok, Understood, I usually do that, But since I was interested to know the error I printed like that, I solved problem already as you mentioned. '$browser.button(:class,'GoButton').click_no_wait'. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby 1.9.3/ IE 9 - I had a click_no_wait error. Watir would not trigger a click on the Save button, which had to be followed by a click on a java popup 'OK' button that confirmed that the save button had saved the document correctly.

Using these two lines in place of the click_no_wait command gets the code working perfectly:

```
element.focus 
element.send_keys :return
```

Thanks DVG. My code -

```
ie.button(:id, 'MainContent_B_Save').focus
ie.button(:id, 'MainContent_B_Save').send_keys :return 
ie. javascript_dialog.button('OK').click
```

Check this : [How to not wait for something with Watir-Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855480/how-to-not-wait-for-something-with-watir-webdriver)